# How to create a comma seperated list as new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe (df) like below.

I also want to skip null values values if any.

**Input**

```
 A            B              C   
a@gmail.com   y@yahoo.com    g@mail.com
b@gmail.com
c@gmail.com   g@gmail.com    d@gmail.com
d@gmail.com                  t@gmail.com
               r@gmail.com   y@gmail.com
```

**Output**

```
 A            B              C             Merged
a@gmail.com   y@yahoo.com    g@mail.com    a@gmail.com,y@yahoo.com,g@mail.com
b@gmail.com                                b@gmail.com
c@gmail.com   g@gmail.com    d@gmail.com   c@gmail.com,g@gmail.com,d@gmail.com
d@gmail.com                  t@gmail.com   d@gmail.com,t@gmail.com
               r@gmail.com   y@gmail.com   r@gmail.com,y@gmail.com
```

How can this be done using pandas?

Comment: @r.ook, I want skip null values any while creating the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As noted by Scott Boston this solution leaves double commas in the merged column in the case of the 4th row.

You could try:

```
df['merged'] = df.A.str.cat([df.B, df.C], sep=',', na_rep='').str.strip(',')
```

This works by concatenating the columns and then stripping the leading and trailing comma's in case of empty values.

Comment: Is there a double comma on index row 3?

Comment: You're right missed that one, not easy to solve using this approach. Your solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Use(Updated to handle '' vs NaN):

```
df.replace('', np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     a@gmail.com, y@yahoo.com, g@mail.com
1                              b@gmail.com
2    c@gmail.com, g@gmail.com, d@gmail.com
3                 d@gmail.com, t@gmail.com
4                 r@gmail.com, y@gmail.com
dtype: object
```

Like,

```
df['merged'] = df.replace('', np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
             A            B            C                                 merged
0  a@gmail.com  y@yahoo.com   g@mail.com   a@gmail.com, y@yahoo.com, g@mail.com
1  b@gmail.com          NaN          NaN                            b@gmail.com
2  c@gmail.com  g@gmail.com  d@gmail.com  c@gmail.com, g@gmail.com, d@gmail.com
3  d@gmail.com          NaN  t@gmail.com               d@gmail.com, t@gmail.com
4          NaN  r@gmail.com  y@gmail.com               r@gmail.com, y@gmail.com
```

Comment: It creates values  like ,, a@gmail.com .When we having missing values other two columns

Comment: Can you add code to create your dataframe in you question.  You can replace the 'None' with np.nan.

Comment: Its coming from excel sheet .I didnt create them

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is `stack` , then join grouping on level=0(rows):

```
df.assign(Merged=df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

Or:

```
df.assign(Merged = df.replace('',np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

---

```
             A            B            C                               Merged
0  a@gmail.com  y@yahoo.com   g@mail.com   a@gmail.com,y@yahoo.com,g@mail.com
1  b@gmail.com          NaN          NaN                          b@gmail.com
2  c@gmail.com  g@gmail.com  d@gmail.com  c@gmail.com,g@gmail.com,d@gmail.com
3  d@gmail.com          NaN  t@gmail.com              d@gmail.com,t@gmail.com
4          NaN  r@gmail.com  y@gmail.com              r@gmail.com,y@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Merged'] = df['A B C'.split()].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
             A            B            C                               Merged
0  a@gmail.com  y@yahoo.com   g@mail.com   a@gmail.com,y@yahoo.com,g@mail.com
1  b@gmail.com         None         None                          b@gmail.com
2  c@gmail.com  g@gmail.com  d@gmail.com  c@gmail.com,g@gmail.com,d@gmail.com
3  d@gmail.com  t@gmail.com         None              d@gmail.com,t@gmail.com
4  r@gmail.com  y@gmail.com         None              r@gmail.com,y@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by mentioned below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'d1': ['abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.cm','abc@gil.com','ab32c@gmail.com'],
        'd2': ['ab3c@g3mail.com','ab32c@gmail.com','ab234c@gma234il.com','abc@htil.com']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['d1', 'd2'])


x = df.to_string(header=False,index=False,index_names=False).split('\n')


df['merged'] = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in x]
```

output :

[image]